# Finding the depth of an element in a binary tree of tuples

Tags: python

I have two functions that operate on the **tuple** `(x, y)` :

```
def f1(t: tuple[int, int]):
    x,y = t
    return (x, x + y)
def f2(t: tuple[int, int]):
    x,y = t
    return (x + y, y)
```

Taking `(1,1)` as the starting tuple, it's clear the two functions can form a binary tree e.g

`(1,1) -> (1,2),(2,1)` and then branching further etc.

My question is there a way to determine the depth of an arbitrary element `(a,b)` or deduce it doesn't exist? Here are some things I've found so far :

- The tree is symmetrical, for example `f1(f1((1,1))) = (1,3)` and `f2(f2((1,1))) = (3,1)`.
- Repeatedly applying `f1` to `(1,1)` gives the edge which looks like `(1,n)`. Then applying `f2` means everything that has the form `(n, n+1)` is in the tree and has depth `n`
- If in `(n,m)` both are even or multiples of each other then this node is not in the tree
- Lastly it seems like for `(n,m)` if `m > n` and `m = k*n + 1` or `m = k*n - 1` for integer `k` then the element is in the tree and its depth can be calculated. This idea comes from the fact `(n, n+1)` is in the tree.

What I'm trying to avoid is actually generating the tree and using DFS for example. It raises other questions also like knowing when to stop generating elements (to see if you've "passed" where the input tuple could be).

Comment: How is `f2(f2(1,1))` even supposed to work when `f2` takes two arguments?

Comment: @ruohola sorry! It comes down to using either two integers separately or using the tuple together. I'll rewrite the function so it works.

Comment: @JobHunter69 Could you elaborate sorry? I think each function takes in a tuple and returns another one right?

Comment: If (x,y) = t, why do you have (x+y)? Why not just (2*x, x)

Comment: y is not necessarily equal to x. In fact, I found that it's only the starting value `(1,1)` where this is true i.e `(5,5)` is not present in the free. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @JobHunter69 Where do you see (x+y)?

Comment: @KellyBundy
def f2(t):
    x,y = t
    return (x + y, y)

Comment: How is y not equal to x when you just assigned "t" to both x,y?

Comment: @JobHunter69 That's (x+y, y), not (x+y). Anyway, looks like you misunderstand what `x,y=t` means?

Comment: @JobHunter69 I'm sorry I wasn't clear in the statement of the problem. t is a tuple. I will add some type hints

Comment: @JobHunter69 You're thinking of `x = y = t`, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go backwards to the root, always subtracting the smaller from the larger. For example:

(7,9) -> (7,2) -> (5,2) -> (3,2) -> (1,2) -> (1,1)

Use division/modulo to speed it up further, e.g., go from (7,2) directly to (1,2), counting that as three steps.

```py
x, y = 7, 9

depth = 0
while y:
    depth += x // y
    x, y = y, x % y
print(depth - 1 if x == 1 else 'not in tree')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3Syt0FCoVbBXMdRQsubhSUgtKMoA8A67yjMycVIVKKy4FIIAIa9sqVCjo6ytUgsWg-ip1gIKqQLGCosy8Eg2ISl0FQ4XMNKCErS2QlZpTnKqgnpdfopCZp1BSlJqqrgmxHOoGmFsA)